# White screen when transitioning between activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-transitions

I have two Activities: A and B. I would like activity B to slide up from the bottom of the screen and cover activity A. I am able to do this, however Activity B is a white screen until it has fully translated into its position, and only then does the content view load. Is there a way to load the activity such that there is content on Activity B's view as it is sliding up?

Here is the code that starts the transition:

`startActivity(ActivityB.newIntent(context));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.hold);`

Comment: Do you populate Activity B's view in `onCreate`? if not, have you tried that?

Comment: Yes Activity B onCreate contains setContentView. I'm not doing anything else in this Activity other than some Butterknife binding. I thought maybe the binding was taking too long, but it turns out that's not it either. It seems like the content view is set only after the transition is complete.

Comment: How much time you are able to see the white screen before the content gets loaded? Is it more than 3-4 seconds?

Comment: Under normal circumstances, there’s not much you can do in terms of pre-creation, you have to respect the Lifecycle and that’s one of the key differences between ViewControllers on iOS and Activities/Fragments on Android. That being said, _maybe_ some of the shared elements transition framework can help you. Take a look at Google’s Example: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html - Alternatively, you could use Fragments, preload them, and simply show/hide via FragmentManager. That’s a lot faster for most of the init code has occurred.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini That's what I was thinking as well. I am at the mercy of the lifecycle unless I figure out how to exploit the shared element transition. Unfortunately I can't use a fragment in this scenario.

Comment: Are you *sure* you can’t use a Fragment? As annoying as they are… any activity can be replaced by a Fragment with enough work (that being the key). I mean, An activity can delegate to a “presenter” (call it anything you like) and the presenter can talk back to the activity via a “policy delegate” (interface/delegate) and so you could intercept intents and messages @ activity level and swap fragments. Anyway, it seems like you know you can’t use fragments so you’re at the mercy of the lifecycle. Remember what Google said: “Act/Frag expose policies"

Comment: source for that quote was somewhere in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3IT-IJ0J98